# Entity was not found in symfony2 twig template

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

In my project I have a table named service_provider.There is a rating system available for each service provider.

My service provider entity,

```
class ServiceProviders
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="service_provider_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $serviceProviderId;


     /**
     * @var \Ratings
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Ratings",inversedBy="serviceProviders",cascade={"all"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="service_provider_id", referencedColumnName="service_provider_id")
     * })
     */
    private $ratings;
}
```

My Rating entity,

```
class Ratings
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="service_provider_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $serviceProviderId;

    /**
     * @var \ServiceProviders
     *
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="ServiceProviders",mappedBy="ratings",cascade={"all"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="service_provider_id", referencedColumnName="service_provider_id")
     * })
     */
    private $serviceProviders;
}
```

and in my serviceProviderEntity I wrote a join query to fetch all data.

```
class ServiceProvidersRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findAllProviders($where,$order,$rowCount,$page)
    {
        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('s')
                ->select('s')
            ->leftJoin('s.ratings','r')
                    ->where('s.status= :status')
            ->andWhere($where)
                ->setParameter('status', 'A')
            ->orderBy($order)
                    ->setMaxResults($rowCount)
                    ->setFirstResult($offset)
                    ->getQuery();
        $result = $query->getResult();
     }
}
```

It all works fine,but when there is no data corresponding to a service provider in rating table,An error occurred in twig template 'Entity was not found'.Can any one help me,how can solve this problem.

My controller action,

```
 public function providerSearchAction()
 {
       $pagination = $entityManager->getRepository('EvpEventpriceBundle:ServiceProviders')->findAllProviders($where,'s.serviceProviderId',$rowCount,$page);
       return $this->render('EvpEventpriceBundle:ServiceProviders:search.html.twig',array('pagination'=>$pagination));
  }
```

And my twig template,

```
{% for provider in pagination %}
     {% for i in 0..4 %}

    {% if provider.ratings|length %}
    {% if (i<((provider.ratings.totalValue/provider.ratings.totalVotes)|number_format)-0.5) %}
        {% set class = "ratings_stars ratings_vote" %}
    {% else %}
        {% set class = "ratings_stars" %}
    {% endif %}
    {% endif %}
    <div class="star_{{i+1}} {{class}}"></div>
    {% endfor %}
```

{% endfor %}

Comment: can you add you twig template?

Comment: and your controller action too please

Answer (score 1):

can you change your 4th line of twig with this and try:

```
{% if provider.ratings is defined and provider.ratings is not empty %}
```

and add `{% set class = "" %}` in case that the test don't instantiate class variable

Comment: Sorry,I already have a return statement in my repository,I forgot to include it in the code snippet.

Comment: can you put the error message in the description To see in which line the exception has launched?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things wrong here:

You are mapping the same database column as a field/column *and* association in your entity. This will make Doctrine very confused! *Always* choose between a field/column *or* association (usually you'll want the association).

Also, you're using `@ORM\JoinColumns` where you shouldn't, `@ORM\JoinColumn` is enough.

*Don't* use cascade options on both sides of the association, this will drastically impact Doctrine's performance. Furthermore, it feels like you put `cascade={"all"}` in there because it sounded convenient when you read the docs (no pun intended). But you should think very carefully when using cascades. Every cascade has a performance penalty, so my advise is to wait using them until you actually need them.

`nullable=FALSE` isn't needed on `@Column`, nullable isn't allowed by default on fields/columns.
They *are* however allowed by default on associations.

You're using the plural form of names where the singular form is better. For example, your entity `ServiceProviders` can better be named `ServiceProvider`, because 1 entity is 1 ServiceProvider (not many ServiceProviders).

I'm not really sure which side of the association you want to be the *owning* side. I'll assume you want `Rating` to be the owning side because you're using `service_provider_id` as foreign key.

Here's the fix to the things I mentioned above:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class ServiceProvider
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Rating", mappedBy="serviceProvider")
     */
    private $rating;

}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Rating
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Customer", inversedBy="rating")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="service_provider_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $serviceProvider;

}
```

You can (and should) always validate your mappings using the console: Doctrine 2: `doctrine orm:validate-schema`, Symfony 2: `app/console doctrine:schema:validate`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and advices.I made the above changes,but still getting the same error.I am new to symfony and doctrine and I got only a limited time to study it.So I am highly confused about most of the things.Can you please tell me how to implement a left join in symfony2 and how to display its results on twig.Or other wise please give me a reference link.

Comment: Can you validate the mappings using the console? What does that output?